# ADOConnection in XE2

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2, ado

I am trying to learn how to use MS Access in XE2.

I have a form with:

- TADOConnection
- TADOTable
- TADOQuery
- TDBGrid

The `ConnectionString` is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Charles\Documents\addressbook.mdb;Persist Security Info=False
```

The "Test Connection" button on the Datalink properties screen says "test Connection Succeeded".

This is the button code:

```
if ADOquery1.Active then ADOquery1.Close;
ADOquery1.SQL.Add('select * from contacts');
ADOquery1.Open;
```

When I click the button, I get an error:

> Missing Connection or ConnectionString

Comment: Did you attach the `TADOQuery` to the `TADOConnection`? Did you connect the `TADOConnection` to the DB before activating the `TADOQuery`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- When you test your connection and you got "Connection Succeeded" then activate your `TADOConnection` , In the Objects Inspector Set the connected property of the `TADOConnection` to True (`Connected = True`).
- For the `TADOQuery` component , the connection is messing , In the Object Inspector , after you click on the `TADOQuery` , You will find `Connection` property , Select your `TADOConnection`.